# numpy: dimensions vs. shape

Tags: numpy, shapes, dimension

I have a just a short question about the attributes shape and ndim. How can an array have more dimensions than two, but matrices are limited to a n x m shape? Would it not be necessary to have shapes with something like a m x n x o shape for a three-dimensional array?

Best regards

Comment: `ndim == len(shape)`

Comment: `np.array` can be any dimension you wish. `np.matrix` is a `specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations`.

Comment: Yes to the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing things here, np.array can have any number of dimensions and np.matrix only two, np.matrix is the specific case where ndim=2 and have special matrix operators. From NumPy documentation of np.matrix:

```
Note:
It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. 
Instead, use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

Returns a matrix from an array-like object, or from a string of data. 
A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations.
It has certain special operators, such as * (matrix multiplication) and ** (matrix power).
```

Also, notice this example so you can see the difference:

```
a = np.matrix([[2,2],[2,2]])
print(a**2)
```

This would return:

```
matrix([[8, 8],
        [8, 8]])
```

Because **matrix** "a" squared is that, but if you do the same thing with array:

```
a = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
print(a**2)
```

It will return:

```
array([[4, 4],
       [4, 4]])
```

Because it applied the square in all elements if you want the behaviour of np.matrix you would have to use np.dot

I think they will probably remove np.matrix in future versions because it doesn't add anything really useful other than bugging the mind of developers.

Comment: @MDoe Does this answer your question? Consider accepting the answer

Comment: Thanks, it did. Still have to get more familiar with the functions of stackoverflow.